# Proof about connectedness

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Here's the question I'm doing.

Let $A,B$ be subspaces such that $A \cup B$ and $A \cap B$ are connected. Suppose that both $A$ and $B$ are open. Then, $A$ and $B$ are connected.

---

It is sufficient to prove that $A$ is connected. Suppose that $A$ is disconnected. Then, $A = U \cup V$, where $U$ and $V$ are open in $A$, disjoint and non-empty. Then:

$$A \cup B = (U \cup V) \cup B = (U \cup B) \cup (V \cup B)$$

Observe that since $A$ is open, $U$ and $V$ are both open. So, $U \cup B$ and $V \cup B$ are open. Moreover, $(U \cup B) \cap (V \cup B) = \varnothing$. Since $A \cup B$ is connected, it follows that $U \cup B$ is empty or $V \cup B$ is empty. WLOG, assume that $U \cup B$ is empty. Then, $U$ is empty and $B$ is empty. This is a contradiction. So, it follows that $A$ is connected. $\Box$

I'm feeling rather uneasy about this argument because it feels like I've missed something, especially since I haven't used the connectedness of $A \cap B$ in the argument. If I've done something wrong, then a hint as to how I could fix it would be nice.

**Edit:**

It is sufficient to prove that $A$ is connected. Suppose that $A$ is disconnected. Then, $A = U \cup V$, where $U$ and $V$ are open in $A$, disjoint and non-empty. Then:

$$A \cup B = (U \cup V) \cup B = (U \cup B) \cup (V \cup B)$$

$$A \cap B = (U \cup V) \cap B = (U \cap B) \cup (V \cap B)$$

Since $A$ is open, both $U$ and $V$ are open. So, $U \cup B$, $V \cup B$, $U \cap B$ and $V \cap B$ are all open. Now:

$$(U \cup B) \cap (V \cup B) = (U \cap V) \cup B = B$$

$$(U \cap B) \cap (V \cap B) = (U \cap V) \cap B = \varnothing$$

Since $A \cap B$ is connected, it follows that $U \cap B = \varnothing$ or $V \cap B = \varnothing$. WLOG, let $U \cap B = \varnothing$. But now, observe that:

$$A \cup B = U \cup (V \cup B)$$

and it is clear that $U \cap (V \cup B) = \varnothing$ since $U$ and $V$ are disjoint. So, $A \cup B$ is disconnected and this is a contradiction. Hence, $A$ is connected. $\Box$

Comment: What makes you conclude that $(U\cup B)\cap(V\cup B)=\varnothing$? The set contains $B$ as subset.

Comment: consider $A=(0,2)\cup(3,5), B=(1,4)$, then $A\cup B=(0,5)$ is connected (but $A\cap B=(1,2)\cap(3,4)$ is disconnected), and $A$ is disconnected. Try and see where your argument fails with this example.

Comment: Oh man, okay, I see where my mistake was. Let me try to fix it now.

Comment: Alright, I've put in an edit. I think it works but it'd be nice to have some confirmation.

Comment: While your proof looks good, I would like to propose an alternate approach. Can you try to use that: "$M$ is connected if and only if any continuous map from $M$ into a discrete space is necessarily constant."?

Comment: I will try working with that in a bit. Is the proof going to be significantly shorter?

Comment: You *must* add the assumption that $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ too.

Comment: But that's not needed, no? In that case, $A \cap B$ is trivially connected? Moreover, I don't think I quite needed the assumption that $A \cap B \neq \varnothing$ at any point in my argument

Comment: @Abhi In regards to one of the previous comments about the *necessity* to add the hypothesis that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint: you certainly can formulate the theorem with this added assumption and it will remain true, but there is certainly no imperative of any kind according to which you *should* or *must* add that assumption. The result remains perfectly valid when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint be it even for trivial reasons.

Comment: Yep that's fair. I was just wondering because the exercise itself didn't include that assumption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider an arbitrary space $(X, \mathscr{T})$ together with open subsets $U, V \in \mathscr{T}$ such that $U \cup V$ and $U \cap V$ are both connected and let us show that $U$ and $V$ must themselves be connected. I would suggest the following approach.

It will suffice to handle the case of $U$ for that of $V$ is to be carried out in complete analogy (by simply interchanging $U$ and $V$). Consider two *relatively* open subsets $W, W' \in \mathscr{T}_{|U}\colon=\{Z \cap U\}_{Z \in \mathscr{T}}$ such that $U=W \cup W'$ and $W \cap W'=\varnothing$. We endeavour to show that either $W=\varnothing$ or $W'=\varnothing$. For simplicity let us write $T=U \cap V$ and $Z=W \cap T=W \cap V$ respectively $Z'=W' \cap T=W' \cap V$. It is clear that $T=T \cap U=Z \cup Z'$, that $Z \cap Z'=\varnothing$ and respectively that $Z, Z' \in \mathscr{T}_{|T}$, whence from the connectedness of $T$ we infer that either $Z=\varnothing$ or $Z'=\varnothing$.

Without any loss of generality, let us assume that $Z'=\varnothing$ which means that $V \cap W'=\varnothing$. Let us now consider the subset $V'\colon=V \cup W$. Since $U$ is open it follows that $\mathscr{T}_{|U} \subseteq \mathscr{T}$, in other words $W$ and $W'$ are *absolutely* open (being relatively open to an open subset). Hence $V' \in \mathscr{T}$ and since obviously $W', V' \subseteq U \cup V$ it is clear that $W', V' \in \mathscr{T}_{|U \cup V}$. Since $U \cup V=W' \cup V'$ and $W' \cap V'=(W' \cap W) \cup (W' \cap V)=\varnothing$, the connectedness of $U \cup V$ entails either $W'=\varnothing$ or $V'=\varnothing$, the latter occurrence clearly leading in its own to $W=\varnothing$ since by construction $W \subseteq V'$. This completes our proof.

Comment: Are you talking about the second proof? Is the second proof incorrect as well? If so, how?

Comment: @Abhi I think that you have expanded on your edit section as I was writing my answer. At the very beginning, the argument you presented in this edit section was not yet conclusive, but now that you brought the editing to an end we've actually produced essentially the same argument.

Comment: Oh alright, that works. I will work through your argument and see if there's anything significantly different from it and my own proof. I will maybe ask you questions if I have any about your proof. Thank you so much, in any event.

Comment: @Abhi Nothing to thank me for really, I am glad you find it in some way useful. By all means do take your time with it (although I can already say as of now that the two arguments are almost identical, save for the difference in notation).

Answer (score 2):

> **Fact:** $X$ is connected iff every continuous $f: X \to \{0,1\}$ is constant, where $\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology.

So let $f: A \to \{0,1\}$ be continuous. Then $f$ is constant on $A \cap B \subseteq A$ because $A \cap B$ is connected, say with value $i_0$.

Define $g: A \cup B \to \{0,1\}$ by

$$g(x)=\begin{cases} i_0 & x \in B\\
                      f(x) & x \in A\\
\end{cases}$$

and note this is well-defined, $g\restriction_A$ and $g\restriction_B$ are continuous and as $A,B$ are both open in $A \cup B$, $g$ is continuous (pasting lemma; also applies when both $A,B$ are closed!) and so constant (with value $i_0$ necessarily), and so $f$ is also constant with that value. Hence $A$ is connected. The proof for $B$ is the same, mutatis mutandis.

Comment: Thank you so much for your proof. One person actually suggested that I prove this result in that way in the comments above so I will try to do that and then use your proof to check against my own.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma It is a very minute detail, but nevertheless special care must be taken in the particular case $A \cap B=\varnothing$. In that case there is no $i_0$ to be had.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ In fact then it's trivial that $A \cup B$ is **not** connected, so part of the assumption of this theorem (omitted by the OP) is that  $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$!

Comment: @HennoBrandsma You seem to be implying that with $A, B$ both open the additional assumption $A \cap B=\varnothing$ entails the failure of $A \cup B$ to be connected, but that is not true. What actually happens is that $A \cup B$ can be connected but - under the additional hypothesis $A \cap B=\varnothing$ - **only** in the very trivial cases $A=\varnothing$ or $B=\varnothing$. Therefore, this additional hypothesis need *not* be made part of the original hypothesis.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ In that case there is nothing to prove anyway.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma There is just this very short and trivial remark to be made, agreed. My whole point is that a proof that aspires to be rigorous and complete should cover all these tiny trivial cases, be it even by addressing them with a few syllables.